PHP/Laravel: Error: Call to a member function __call() on null
I’m currently working on a Laravel project and I’m facing an issue with setting up a factory for a pivot table. Specifically, I’m trying to create a factory for a table that serves as a pivot between Order and Product models. The table is named order_product and includes fields such as order_id, product_id, quantity, and price.
The test looks like this:
public function testCalculateOrderTotal(): void
    {
        $address = Address::factory()->create();
        $client = Client::factory()->create(['address_id' => $address->id]);
        $order = Order::factory()->create(['client_id' => $client->id]);
        $product1 = Product::factory()->create();
        $product2 = Product::factory()->create();

        $orderProductData1 = [
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'product_id' => $product1->id,
            'quantity' => 2,
            'price' => 100.00
        ];
        $orderProductData2 = [
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'product_id' => $product2->id,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'price' => 150.00
        ];

        $orderProduct1 = OrderProduct::factory()->create($orderProductData1);
        $orderProduct2 = OrderProduct::factory()->create($orderProductData2);

        $this->orderProductRepository
            ->shouldReceive('findByOrder')
            ->with($order->id)
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(new Collection([$orderProduct1, $orderProduct2]));

         $expectedTotal = ($orderProductData1['quantity'] * $orderProductData1['price']) +
             ($orderProductData2['quantity'] * $orderProductData2['price']);

         $total = $this->orderProductService->calculateOrderTotal($order->id);

         $this->assertIsFloat($total);
         $this->assertEquals($expectedTotal, $total);
    }

and this is the service method which I'm trying to test
    public function calculateOrderTotal($order_id): float
    {
        try {
            $orderProducts = $this->orderProductRepository->findByOrder($order_id);
            return $orderProducts->sum(fn($item) => $item->quantity * $item->price);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            throw $th;
        }
    }

and when I run all the tests (./vendor/bin/sail exec -T laravel.test ./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html=coverage/) it keeps returning:
 FAILED  Tests\Unit\Services\OrderProductServiceTest > calculate order total                                                                                                                             Error   
  Call to a member function __call() on null

  at tests/Unit/Services/OrderProductServiceTest.php:56
  ➜  56▕ $orderProduct1 = OrderProduct::factory()->create($orderProductData1);
     57▕ $orderProduct2 = OrderProduct::factory()->create($orderProductData2);
     58▕ 

1   tests/Unit/Services/OrderProductServiceTest.php:56
My OrderProductFactory looks like this:
public function definition(): array
{
return [
    'order_id' => Order::factory(),
    'product_id' => Product::factory(),
    'quantity' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 10),
    'price' => $this->faker->randomFloat(2, 5, 100),
];
}

I've tried to update my OrderProductFactory but that didn't work.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

remove your code modification on any file inside vendor folder. or delete the vendor folder and run composer install to get a fresh copy.

Could you also share the full stack trace? We need to find what is null, as your factory and your test looks good, so there is something more not being set or not getting data back

@matiaslauriti
`

Tests\Unit\Services\OrderProductServiceTest::testCalculateOrderTotal
Error: Call to a member function __call() on null

/var/www/html/tests/Unit/Services/OrderProductServiceTest.php:56
`

@barbgluz you have to edit the question and put it there, but the full stack trace, not one line

@matiaslauriti I have updated the question but the error doesn't say much. It just complains about line 56

You will then need to do minimum debugging, for example, remove quantity from the factory, then remove price, then hardcode product_id to any number (does not need to exist). All of this is to check who is creating this error

@matiaslauriti thanks for the advice but that didn't work. OrderProduct is a pivot table. Is there anything else I should do inside the factory to configure the relationships between orderProduct and orders/products?

I don't know if there's something wrong with the factory because when I seed the database it works and populates correctly

This does not look hard. But before helping you resolve this problem, I got a few questions of my own:

How do you instantiate that $orderProductService variable? via the service container or just new up the object?

How do you instantiate that $orderProductRepository inside the OrderProductService class? Is that a dependency like this?


class OrderProductService
{
    protected $orderProductRepository;

    public function __construct(OrderProductRepository $orderProductRepository)
    {
        $this->orderProductRepository = $orderProductRepository;
    }
}


I see you are mocking the OrderProductRepository class. Reading [the docs][1], it has to be mocked this way:

$this->mock(OrderProductRepository::class, function ($mock) use ($order) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('findByOrder')
        ->with($order->id)
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(new Collection([$orderProduct1, $orderProduct2]));
});

Still, I find mocking in this context unnecessary. That findByOrder method is simple and should return the correct results anyway. You can just remove this line.
Let us know, so we can help you resolve.
